# What is the correct way of adding parameter to ignore case for search text in a REST API

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I have an API endpoint to retrieve all users. There are 3 query parameters for searching/filtering the results as follows.

```
GET /users?name=test&age=23&area=abc
```

Now I want to introduce an option to ignore the case when searching for the `name` parameter. For example, the above API call should return even if the name equals `Test` or `tesT`.

What's the correct way of implementing this option? Adding another query parameter or is there any better way of implementing it?

Comment: Another query parameter sounds fine to me!

Comment: @Evert in that case what's the parameter name you suggest? `ignore-case=true`? But the thing is it is only applying to the `name` parameter for now

Comment: I'd probably go for `case-sensitive=false`.  If you want to make it very clear it's only about the `name` property you could add `name-case-sensitive`.

Comment: I don't think there's like a standard for this, so try to do something you think would be easy for a user of the API to understand ;)

Comment: Thanks @Evert , maybe you can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, an easier option could be to define the query parameter value as a regex expression, since regex expression itself allows us to define a string to be case insensitive / sensitive.

In other scenarios, another option would be to incorporate the specification (that the value needs to be case insensitive) into the query param value itself, like

`http://localhost:3000?name=case_insensitive(test)`

Comment: Thanks, regex would be a nice option

Answer (score 1):

I would realize two new parameters for *name*, namely: *nameIgnoreCase* and *nameCaseSensitive*. In this case the user of the endpoint can and must decide. If this is well documented, the user gets an additional hint that this ‚question’ exists at all.
You can also continue to provide *name* as the default behavior, which will fall back to either *nameIgnoreCase* or *nameCaseSensitive*.